# Handle not Allocated on setting form property on Android in Delphi XE7

Tags: android, forms, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm having problem opening a new form that i've created in XE7. I have no problems opening the form on my Samsung Galaxt tab2, but when I want to open it on my Sony Xperia ZR I get a Handle not Allocated exception.

**Here is the code:**

```
procedure TfrmNocoreDKS.actOpenDocumentExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  frmDKSDocument: TfrmDKSDocument;
begin
  frmDKSDocument := TfrmDKSDocument.Create(nil);
  frmDKSDocument.ScaleBy := fScaleBy; 
  frmDKSDocument.UseAantal := fUseAantal;
  frmDKSDocument.DocumentId := TButton(Sender).Tag;
  frmDKSDocument.LoadDocument;
  frmDKSDocument.SetDocumentStatus := SetDocumentStatus;
  frmDKSDocument.Allowresize := True;
  frmDKSDocument.Show;
  frmDKSDocument.FillSigns;
end;
```

**Code below shows the decleration of the property and the setter:**

```
TfrmDksDocument = class(TForm)
private
  fScaleBy:Single;
public
  property ScaleBy:Single read fScaleBy write SetScaleBy;

procedure TfrmDksDocument.SetScaleBy(const Value: Single);
begin
  fScaleBy := Value;
  sgnController.ScaleBy := fScaleBy; //sgnController is a Custom Image component
  sgnController.setbitmap; //Here I get the exception
  sgnCustomer.ScaleBy := fScaleBy; //sgnCustomeris a Custom Image component
  sgnCustomer.setbitmap;
end;
```

**Code for the SetBitmap method:**

```
procedure TisImage64.SetBitmap;
begin
  {$IFDEF WIN32}
  if not fBitmapCreated then
  Begin
    self.Bitmap := TBitMap.Create;
    self.Bitmap.SetSize(integer(trunc(Self.Size.Width)), integer(trunc(Self.Size.Height)));
    fBitmapCreated := True;
    self.clear;
  End;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
    self.Bitmap := MultiResBitMap.Add.Bitmap; //.Add.Bitmap;
    self.Bitmap.SetSize(integer(trunc(Self.Size.Width*fScaleBy)), integer(trunc(Self.Size.Height*fScaleBy)));
    fBitmapCreated := True;
    self.Clear;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF IOS}
    self.Bitmap := MultiResBitMap.Add.Bitmap; //.Add.Bitmap;
    self.Bitmap.SetSize(integer(trunc(Self.Size.Width*fScaleBy)), integer(trunc(Self.Size.Height*fScaleBy)));
    fBitmapCreated := True;
    self.Clear;
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

**Anyone knows a solution?**

Comment: I think this needs more information.  `.ScaleBy` is a method in VCL forms but it does not exist as a property on FMX forms so it is something you have added.  What is its declaration?  Is it actually a property?  Does it have a setter?  What is `fScaleBy`?  Is it a method with a return value?  If so, what is its implementation?  If not, where and how is it defined?  Are you sure that is the line causing the exception?  The instruction pointer often moves ahead when an exception is raised - did you step through your `TfrmDKSDocument` constructor to be sure the exception is not there?

Comment: Including a call stack would be helpful as well.

Comment: @J... I've checked and the problem definitly is the ScaleBy property and it's a property i've created. When I want to set the bitmap in SetScaleBy method it gives the exception. sgnController and sgnCustomer are both custom image components.

Comment: ok...so which line in the setter is throwing the exception?  You can set a breakpoint on `fScaleBy := Value;` and step through with `F7` if you haven't done that already.  What are `sgnController` and `sgnCustomer`?  If the exceptions are being thrown there, do their `ScaleBy` properties have setters?    If so, what does their code look like?  What does `setbitmap` do?  Drill down until you find which exact line is causing the problem - again, a call stack would tell us this immediately.

Comment: An invalid handle leads me to suspect the calls to `.setbitmap` - trying to draw to an invalid context, etc... Much easier if you do some debugging and report back, however.

Comment: @J... I've found the problem. It actually didn't have anything to do with the code but the size of the component. Apparently it wasn't set correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to have been your rubber duck.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging  ;)

Comment: @J... Strange though that it did work for my samsung and didn't for my sony :S

Comment: Suppose you could repeat the above process on the Sony and see what's different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of 2 image components weren't set properly